# Why does creating a Hibernate Criteria without adding a Restriction effect my results?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class `AttributeGroup` that has a many-to-one relationship with a class `Attribute`. Given either an `AttributeGroup` name or an `Attribute` name or both, I'd like to return an appropriate join of the data. Here is my initialization code:

```
Criteria criteria = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(AttributeGroup.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

That's all fine. If I return that `List` by calling `criteria.list()`, I get every `AttributeGroup` in my database. What's odd is if I add this line next:

```
Criteria attributesCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("attributes");
```

In that case, an empty `List` is returned.  What's happening? My understanding is that `attributesCriteria` should have no effect until I add a `Restriction`. What I would *like* to do next is this:

```
if (attribute != null) {
    attributesCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", attribute));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and Add restriction to below criteria.

```
Criteria criteria = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(AttributeGroup.class)
        .createCriteria("attributes").setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

`createCriteria` and almost all `Criteria` methods modify the instance they're invoked on, and **return the instance itself** for method chanining. So you can chain calls like above.

Comment: Right, I am trying to create two instances. This allows me to reuse an instance of `attributesCriteria`. With what you're proposing, how can I re-access the subcriteria "attributes"?